# TensorFlow or Pytorch: Neural Network for classification - Constrain some weights to be chosen from a finite set

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

When training Neural Networks for classification in TensorFlow/Keras, or Pytorch, is it possible to put constraints on the weights in the output layer such that they are chosen from a specific finite feasible set?

For example, let's say W is the weight in the output layer, is it possible to put constraints on W such that the optimal W is selected from the set S={W_1, W_2, ..., W_n}, where each W_i is a given feasible value for W? i.e. I will give the values of the W_1,...,W_n to the model

If this is not possible in TensorFlow or Pytorch, is there any other ways to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Sounds to me like you're trying to abuse a regression architecture to do classification.

Comment: Yes, I'm training neural network for classification problems

Comment: This feels like a combinatorial problem rather than a machine learning problem. I really doubt that TF or PyTorch would support this, since their cores are gradient method-focused. However, your problem is similar to quantization (albeit you need to do it before training, which is unconventional), so I hope you'll find something there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you might be looking is something similar to set weights of a layer using [set_weights](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#set_weights) in `Tensorflow`.
If that doesn't help your cause then you can check Tensorflow's [Custom Layers.](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers)